# how to cluster percentile of events by time delta?

Tags: influxdb

After a mailing at t0, I will have several "delivered" (and open and click) events (schema and example)

```
mailing_name, timestamp, email_id, event_type
niceattack, 2016-07-14 12:11:00, 42, open
niceattack, 2016-07-14 12:11:08, 842, open
niceattack, 2016-07-14 12:11:34, 847, open
```

I would like to see for a mailing how long it takes to be delivered to half of the recipients. So say that I'm sending an email to 1000 addresses now, the first open event is in 2 min, the last one is going to be in a week (and min/max first last seems to be easy to find) but what I'd like to see is that half of the recipients opened it in the first 2 hours after it was sent.

The goal is to send being able to compare is sending now vs on sat morning makes a difference on how fast it's open on average, or if one specific mailing get quicker exposure, and correlate that with other events (how many click on a link, take a specific action on our site...)

I tried to use a cumulate function (how many open event for mailing for each point), but it seems that the cumulative function isn't yet implemented https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb/issues/813

How do you solve that problem with influxdb?

Comment: Can you explain what you're trying to do a little bit more. I'm not sure I understand.

Comment: sure, updated the question with a more complete description on what I'd like to find out.

Comment: So I don't think is possible with InfluxDB alone, however with some external tooling it should be possible.

Answer (score 0):

Solving this problem with InfluxDB alone is not currently possible, however if you're willing to add [Kapacitor](https://github.com/influxdata/kapacitor) into the mix, then it should be possible. In particular you'll need to write a User Defined Function (UDF) for that cumulative function in Kapacitor.

The general process will look like the following:

1. Install and Configure Kapacitor
2. Create a UDF for the cumulative function you're looking for
3. Enable that UDF inside of Kapacitor
4. Write a `TICKscript` that uses the UDF and writes the results back to InfluxDB
5. Enable a task defined by the `TICKscript` you've written
6. Query the InfluxDB instance to get the results of the cumulative function.

My appoligies for being so high level on this. This is a fairly involved process, but should give you the result you're looking for.